# Successful API call but no data returned

Tags: json, api, python-requests

I'm trying to request data from api.travelpayouts to find cheap flights, but even after trying exact examples from their documentation I'm not returning any data.

The code I'm using (with example fields from the website* and my authorisation keys) is:

```
    import requests
    url = "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap"
    querystring = {"origin":"MOW","destination":"HKT","depart_date":"2019-11","return_date": "2019-12"}
    headers = {'x-access-token': 'xxxx'}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    print(response.json())
```

- https://travelpayouts.github.io/slate/

According to the example, the return should be:

```
    {
"success": true,
"data": {
    "HKT": {
        "0": {
            "price": 35443,
            "airline": "UN",
            "flight_number": 571,
            "departure_at": "2015-06-09T21:20:00Z",
            "return_at": "2015-07-15T12:40:00Z",
            "expires_at": "2015-01-08T18:30:40Z"
        }}
    }
}
```

but I receive:

```
{'success': True, 'data': {}, 'currency': 'rub'}
```

If anyone could give me some tips I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: On the parameter `depart_date` it says:  "Day or month of departure (yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-mm). Old dates may be specified in a query. No error will be generated, but no data will be returned."  Try to send newer (=current) dates could help...

Comment: BTW: It is not smart to post your `x-access-token` here ....

Answer (score 0):

I tried in insomnia app and no data  [pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clfmh.png)